# Cannot create simple class

Tags: c#, constructor

I am trying to create a very simple CUser class in my project, but apparently I am doing something wrong. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace admin.NET.lib {
    public class CUser {
        protected MySqlConnection conn;

        public void CUser() {
        }
    }
}
```

This simple piece of code gives me:

```
'CUser': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

Can anyone give me a hint to where I must modify this to work. I saw that this problem poped before but I could not adapt the solutions to my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `void`. Constructors have no return type.

Answer (score 0):

Bad constructor. Read .net base information.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what I said? Also, reading .NET "base information" won't help him. He would need to read C# "base information".

Answer (score 0):

`public CUser() { }`
Would be better !

Your contructor returns a reference to the object it create, this is his job :-).